# Can a causative have an indirect object?

Tags: grammar

Can a causative have an indirect object?  For example: **I made my friends give me a new phone**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Me* there is the indirect object of *give*, not of the causative *make*.

Catenating causatives like *make*, *let*, *have* don't really take "objects"—they take clausal **complements**. Pronominal subjects of infinitival complement clauses are often cast in "object" case—transformational grammars call this "raising to object"—but they are only morphologically objective, objects-by-position rather than objects-in-fact.